# The type of expression must be an array type but it is resolved to a string?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I'm trying to integrate a "Next" button in my jokes app. I'm getting the error on         textView.setText(*message*[currentSelectedJoke]);  **I KNOW** this error means that "message" is a string but it expects an array. I understand the problem. My question is, how do I fix this?? 
THANKS SO MUCH!

**[ALL MY JOKES ARE INSIDE MY STRINGS]** 
My code :

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

Button next; 
int currentSelectedJoke =0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

 textView.setText(message);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    textView.setTextSize(26);
    textView.setTypeface(berlin);
    ///INPUT THIS FOR SOLID COLOR ///textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);


    // Set the text view as the activity layout
     setContentView(textView);
    textView.setText(message[currentSelectedJoke]);

    next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);

    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            currentSelectedJoke++;


            if(currentSelectedJoke == 5){
                currentSelectedJoke =0;}

            textView.setText(message[currentSelectedJoke]);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Where are you declaring `message`

Comment: textview is not initialized.

Comment: The problem with that is that I have 104 jokes. It would be much easier if I would be able to tell it to accept the string. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: Why not just make an array of your 104 strings(jokes) and use that?

Comment: You have `textView.setText(message);` and a few lines later `textView.setText(message[currentSelectedJoke]);`. This does not go together.

Comment: @RaghavSood because that's the variable for the jokes in my strings.

Comment: you have twice setContentView's  `setContentView(textView)` and then you `next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next)`. there are so many errors

Comment: "@RaghavSood because that's the variable for the jokes in my strings"...this doesn't answer his question of WHERE/how you are declaring the variable

Comment: @Raghunandan Actually, this is my only error. I have done everything else correctly.

Comment: @Tashad i don't think so there are so many errors i see. you have twice `setContentView` in the same activtiy which itself is not a good design. textview is not initialized you set this `setContentView(textView)` and then initialize `next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next)`. what is your message?

Comment: post the original code, the same you are compiling

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
textView.setText(new String[]{message[currentSelectedJoke]});
```

That will create an array with the selected joke only...

Comment: I don't understand why (s)he wouldn't just create an array of all the jokes. Either way, this answer will solve the issue if all you want is to solve the data type conflict